# Using the ZTE MF192 HSPA USB Modem with Network Manager in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb-modem, zte

Has anyone been able to use the ZTE MF192 HSPA (Black) modem with Network Manager?
If there's a way, please share with the rest of us.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same modem same problem, gave me headache till I found the magical solution, Sakis3g!
Follow the instructions under "ubuntu" on http://wiki.sakis3g.org/wiki/index.php?title=Sakis3G_installation 
You might want to eject the cd-rom icon that appears first, until your modem light blinks blue. Then double click the script to run.
Works 100% for me. Dunno what's up with the Orange dudes btw.

Answer (score 1):

I got this device working with two steps:

1) Use this config file for usb_modeswitch (/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:1216):

```
########################################################
# ZTE MF192+ (PPP and pseudo-ethernet interfaces)

DefaultVendor= 0x19d2
DefaultProduct=0x1216

TargetVendor = 0x19d2
TargetProduct= 0x1217

MessageContent="555342430800498200000000000010FF000000000000000000000000000000"
```

2) With this config NetworkManager is able to connect, but dhcp client should be started manually:

```
sudo dhclient usb0
```

Or, patch modemmanager with this patch: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2012-April/msg00043.html

Comment: Alexander,
I tried out your link above, but don't know how to patch the modem manager. What do I have to do? - Martin