# Ubuntu cant detect ZTE MF193 USB Modem

Tags: modem

When I plug my modem (ZTE mf193) on my 14.04 (32 bit) I dont get any CD-ROM drive in my ubuntu panel. that means ubuntu cant detect my modem. But the **Disks** tool can detect my modem. 
**lsusb** command is :  `Bus 001 Device 015: ID 19d2:1588 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM`
In my modem manual book I saw that the modem support with 32 bit ubuntu of 12.04, 12.10, 13.04. But the modem is not working with my 14.04 (32 bit).
Is there any solution?
If I cant connect my modem then I cant install any apps in my ubuntu :-(
Anyone help me please?

Comment: This should stil work: http://askubuntu.com/a/142219/15811 this method is independent of Ubuntu versions. More detailed version: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2012-April/msg00043.html